# Display data in a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a datatable that lists Agencies, Contacts, and Groups which in the end result will be bound to a repeater control via list. So far I am able to pull the information I need, but am having trouble with obtaining the distinct values for the Agencies and Contacts. There are duplicate agencies as well as Contacts that have one or more groups.

It should resemble this structure:

```
Agency1 
   Jenny    |  Basketball, Dance
   Bill     | Football, Ballet
Agency2
   Archie   |  Soccer, Band
```

So far I have this:

```
var groups = dt.AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(r => new
{
    Agency = r.Field<string>(("Agency")),
   //Contact = r.Field<string>("POC") ,
   //Groups = r.Field<string>("POC_Name")
});


List<alist> agencyAdd = new List<alist>();
foreach (var agencyContactGroup in groups)
{
    agencyAdd.Add(new alist()
    {

      Agency = agencyContactGroup.Key.Agency,
      Contact = string.Join("<br>", agencyContactGroup.Select(r => r.Field<string>("POC")))
              + string.Join(",",  agencyContactGroup.Select(g => g.Field<string>("POC_Name")))
    });
}
```

and on the .aspx side:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="AgencyRepeater">
<HeaderTemplate> <h2>Agency:</h2> </HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>
          <td><h3><b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Agency") %></b></h3></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
             <b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Contact") %></b>
             <b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Groups") %></b>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>   
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: So, you have problems with getting grouped data, or with displaying data on UI?

Comment: Both, in the end, displaying it on the UI is the most important.

Comment: then I think it should be two different questions targeting some specific issues

Comment: so the way i am doing it is not possible

Comment: @jpavlov can you show sample how bind data to repeater control?

Comment: AgencyRepeater.DataSource = agencyAdd;
            AgencyRepeater.DataBind();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use linq group by, with a nested repeater/listview control. You can use the linq `IGrouping` `Key` property to display the group header, and the items can be any type. Here is a sample of how this would be applied to your scenario. Hopefully this helps.

```
Groupings.DataSource = agencyAdd.GroupBy(a=> a.Agency.Name);
Groupings.Databind();

<asp:ListView ID="Groupings" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled" EnableViewState="false">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <Table>
              <tbody>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ItemPlaceHolder" />
              </tbody>
        </Table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <!-- group header -->
        <tr><td colspan="3"><%# Eval("Key") %></td></tr> 

        <!-- group items -->
        <asp:ListView ID="GroupItems" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Container.DataItem %>' ViewStateMode="Disabled" EnableViewState="false">
        <LayoutTemplate>
           <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ItemPlaceHolder" />
        </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
              <tr>
                <td> </td>
                </td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Contact") %></td>
                </td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Groups") %></td>
              </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
    </ItemTemplate>     
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The grouping query should be something like this:

```
dt.AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Agency"))
.Select(g => 
    new AgencyDto { 
          Agency = g.Key,
          Contacts = g.GroupBy(r1 => r1.Field<string>("POC"))
            .Select(g1 => 
              new ContactDto { 
                    Contact = g1.Key, 
                    Groups = string.Join(",", g1.Select(r2 => r2.Field<string>("POC_Name")))
                  })
        })
```

So there is a grouping by `Agency` first and within these groups there are groups of `Contacts`, having their `Groups` concatenated as one comma-separated string.

I'm assuming you'll create the `AgencyDto` and the `ContactDto` types.